# How to pickle datetime in Python 3 to be read by Python 2

Tags: python, datetime, pickle

I am working on upgrading a Python script from 2 to 3. It sends pickled data to a server. I do not have access to the server-side code, only the client. The server is still running Python 2.

The problem is that datetime pickling is different between 2 and 3, and is encoded in latin-1 while the server is expecting utf-8. I need to be able to send a datetime pickled in Python 3 to a server unpickling using Python 2.

I have been searching for a solution but everything I could find is going in the other direction - that is, how to convert a pickle from python 2 to be readable by python 3. There is an option to set the encoding in the load function, but it's the server that uses load, not my code. I am using dumps, which does not have an encoding option.

Here's an example:

```py
myPickle = pickle.dumps({'mytime': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 12, 15, 14, 19)}, protocol=0)
    print(myPickle)
```

Running this code in Python 2 (with import cPickle) gives me

```
(dp1
S'mytime'
p2
cdatetime
datetime
p3
(S'\x07\xe3\t\x0c\x0f\x0e\x13\x00\x00\x00'
tRp4
s.
```

But running it in Python 3 (with import pickle, since the name changed) gives me

```
b'(dp0\nVmytime\np1\ncdatetime\ndatetime\np2\n(c_codecs\nencode\np3\n(V\x07\xe3\t\x0c\x0f\x0e\x13\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\np4\nVlatin1\np5\ntp6\nRp7\ntp8\nRp9\ns.'
```

And when I send that to the server I get:

```
400 Bad Request
The request entity could not be decoded. The following charsets were attempted: ['utf-8']
```

Is there a way to get pickle in Python 3 to output the datetime in the same format as it does in Python 2? I have tried adding fix_imports=True but the output was identical.

Comment: Picking is not a good way to make things interoperable across different object implementations. Consider using a proper independent serialization format (json, protobuf, thrift, etc) if you want to pass data between different _internal representations_. That could work if you pickled your own class that you can have the same version of both on client and server, but this is a part of stdlib. For now, I'd suppose you're locked to Python 2 in the client.

Comment: Why not using epoch?

Comment: @geckos the server is specifically expecting a datetime object. I do not have control over what the server wants.

Comment: @9000 That's good to know for the future; at some point we might be updating the server code. So do you think I should just leave updating this script until that time comes?

Comment: @apocrita: I'm not sure what your priorities are, but I'm certain that making Python 3 emit pickled data generated from its datetime objects in a way compatible with Python 2's datetime objects is going to be involved. It of course _can_ be done, because Python 2's code for that is available, and can be adapted. But I'd rather have _very_ pressing reasons before I chose to follow this approach.

Comment: In the Python 3 code, try explicitly specifying `protocol=0` in the `dump()` call, which the Python 2 server should be able to understand. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump).

Comment: `python3 -c 'import pickle; import datetime; print(pickle.dumps(datetime.datetime.now()))' | python2 -c 'import sys; import pickle; d = pickle.loads(sys.stdin.read()); print(d)'` does this reproduces your problem?